# Django to AWS: favicon, robots.txt and sitemap?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, robots.txt, favicon

I've deployed a Django website to Elastic Beanstalk using this tutorial:
https://realpython.com/blog/python/deploying-a-django-app-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

But, I have no idea where and how to put a favicon.ico, a robots.txt and a sitemap.xml. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For the `favicon.ico` and `sitemap.xml` you can put them in the `static/` directory and refer to them in the template with the static URL. E.g.:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{{STATIC_URL}}/favicon.ico"/>
```

Your `robots.txt` is a bit harder (as with any django app). You can drop it into the `templates` directory and in your `urls.py` have the following:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    (r'^robots\.txt$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='robots.txt', content_type='text/plain')),
)
```

Comment: direct_to_template seems to be deprecated.

Comment: @Antoni4040 - you're right, moved to `TemplateView` present in newer Djangos

Answer (score 1):

To get your sitemaps working, you can use a `django.contrib.sitemaps` framework: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sitemaps/). Or if you have a static amount of pages just do like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # your robots.txt (and/or humans.txt) file:
    url(r'^robot\.txt$', TemplateView.as_view(
        template_name='txt/robots.txt',
        content_type='text/plain'
    )),
    # your static sitemap:
    url(r'^crossdomain\.xml$', TemplateView.as_view(
        template_name='txt/sitemap.xml',
        content_type='application/xml'
    )),
]
```

For the `favicon.ico` place it inside your `static` folder and use this template tag in your template:

```
<link rel="icon" href="{% static 'path/to/favicon.ico' %}" sizes="...">
```

Do not forget to support all of the devices: [full list of favicons](https://github.com/audreyr/favicon-cheat-sheet)

Comment: Where should I put robots.txt and sitemap.xml for this to work?

Comment: I used those urlpatterns, but when I deploy my website and check using an SEO checker website, it doesn't find the robots.txt and sitemap.xml files. The favicon works great.

Comment: Yes, I seem to be able to do that